# jQuery Simpler Way to Do True Slideup/Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to do **true** sliding with jQuery (so the element actually slides up), I came up with the following, i'm not sure it's very optimised, can you see a way to improve it?

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/gpuHG/1/

The idea is the .content elements default to being up by their height so they are off the page or behind a header, and when an item on the menu is clicked if any windows are open they close and then the requested item slides down. My solution seems rather bloated for something so simple!

jQuery:

```
$.fn.exists = function() {
    return this.length !== 0;
}

$(".content").each(function() {
    $(this).hide().css({
        "margin-top": "-=" + $(this).outerHeight() + "px"
    });
});

$("#navigation ul li").each(function() {
    var relatedContent = $("#" + $(this).attr("title") + "-content");
    $(this).click(function() {
        if (!$(":animated").exists()) {
            if ($(".open").exists()) {
                $(".current").first().removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
                var element = $(".open").first();
                element.removeClass("open").animate({
                    "margin-top": "-" + element.outerHeight() + "px"
                }, 500, function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                    relatedContent.show().addClass("open").animate({
                        "margin-top": "0px"
                    }, 500);
                });
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("current");
                relatedContent.show().addClass("open").animate({
                    "margin-top": "0px"
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Every time I do animations with jQuery, it seems that I end up with a whole lot of nested blocks like this.

Comment: @ExplosionPills its just a check to see if the element could be found. Commonly, you would see code like `if($('#something').length){...}` and Pez has just provided a jQuery plugin to do the same thing. It reads easier to say `if($('#something').exists()){...}` although it might be a tiny performance hit.

Comment: @lbstr ah I see it now.  Could be nice in jQuery core but it's probably inefficient/bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, your code is fine, so I didn't change much. Remember to cache variables as much as possible; DOM access is expensive. Also, providing a context to your selectors will improve performance. There are many more tweaks you could make to this, but here are a few:

```
var $nav = $('#navigation');
$nav.find("ul li").click(function(){
    if($(':animated').length) { return; }
    var $this = $(this),
        relatedContent = $("#"+$this.attr("title")+"-content", $nav);
    if(!relatedContent.length) { return; }
    if($(".open", $nav).length) {
        $(".current", $nav).removeClass("current");
        $this.addClass("current");
        var element = $(".open", $nav).first();
        element.removeClass("open").animate({"margin-top": "-"+element.outerHeight()+"px"},
            500,
            function() {
                $(this).hide();
                relatedContent.show().addClass("open").animate({"margin-top": "0px"},500);
            });
    } else {
        $this.addClass("current");
        relatedContent.show().addClass("open").animate({"margin-top": "0px"},500); 
    }
});​
```

**EDIT:**
I agree with the comment above: your `$.fn.exists` function is great for convenience, but using `.length` is shorter and faster than hitting an additional function. Keep it if you like, but I'm ditching it in my code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I had to make some changes to your code as there were a few (non syntactical) bugs but certainly reminded me of a few things, thanks! End product at http://labs.pezcuckow.com/joe/#home